# How to call API in c# using angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, ajax, razor, asp.net-web-api2

Hi I am calling my API using below code

```
  $http.get('/api/controller/method?param=value').
           then(function (response) {
               if (response.status == 200) {
                   console.log(response.data);
               }
           });
```

It is working fine in my local machine (http://localhost/api/controller/method?param=value).

But when I deployed it in server with application name ***app***, it is not able to call the API(http://server-ip/app/api/controller/method?param=value).

Obviously, it won't, as URL are different. **So what is the correct way to call an API in c# so that it will work in any server**.

What I have tried:
1. **URL.Action** : It is not working in this case.
2. I don't want to Use **@HTML.hidden** 
3. Call starting with or without  slash (/)

Comment: will you try this: http://server-ip/api/controller/method?param=value (i.e. replace localhost with your domain name)

Comment: that is working...but by default angularJS is calling "http://server-ip/app" like this..

Comment: Api Url is all about Api Routing. If you want to call the api like `server-api/app` you need to change api route config in webApi.config file.

Comment: you should add web.config transform to change your main url from localhost to your-server-address.

Answer (score 1):

I usually solve this by using a `factory` like this -

First in the .cshtml page I load all the angular js required.
Then create a factory for the baseURL like this -

```
function(angular){
    var module = angular.module('NameOfMyModule');  //gt the module
    module.factory('BaseUrl', function(){
         return '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")';
    });
}(window.angular);
```

Then inject that `BaseURL` inside the controller -

```
....
module.controller('SomeController', [...., 'BaseUrl', function(...., BaseUrl){
     $scope.baseUrl = BaseUrl;

}]);

....`
```

Finally prepend it in the url

```
$http.get($scope.baseUrl + /...../).then(....);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I undestood your question correctly, but I'm using angular constant to set server url

```
angular.constant("CONSTS", {
    "DEV_URL": "http://localhost:12345",
    "LIVE_URL": "http://server-ip/app"
})
```

and then in $http call

```
$http.get(CONSTS.DEV_URL + '/api/controller/method?param=value').
    then(function (response) {
        if (response.status == 200) {
            console.log(response.data);
        }
});
```

I'm sure there is a way to automate this (gulp, grunt), but I didn't get there yet.
When deploying the app I would just manually change the constant.
If I'll find outomatic way to it I'll update the answer.

Hope this helps a bit...

Comment: You understood my question correctly. But I don't think, it is a correct way to do it.

Comment: i'll leave the answer, hopefuly someone will post a better one, I'd like to know better way as well...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your build process etc. but usually you can store application path in some constant value in Angular and use it when calling your API as a prefix.

If you have some kind of automated build, it is easy to prepare deployment packages with changed values(by using Gulp/Grunt/TeamCity/Octopus, whatever you like).

Answer (score 0):

```js
//controller
app.controller("sampleController", function($scope, commonService) {

  //post
  $scope.postData = function() {
    var command = {}
    commonService.postSample(command);
  }

  //get
  commonService.getSample().then(function(data) {
    $scope.permissionList = data;
  });

});



//service
app.service('commonService', function($http, $q) {

  this.postSample = function(command) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        data: command,
        url: '/Attendance/CreatePersonDailyLeave'
      })
      .success(function(data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
      })
      .error(function(data) {
        deferred.reject(data);
      });
    return deferred.promise;
  }


  this.getSample = function(id) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        async: true,
        url: '/Attendance/GetRoles?id=' + id
      })
      .success(function(data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
      })
      .error(function(data) {
        deferred.reject(data);
      });
    return deferred.promise;
  }

});
```